# How to edit data in a database in with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I want to know how I go about selecting a voter in the database table and edit the information with a form in Codeigniter. I already created a search table for it and will post the code below.

Model:

```
public function search_voters($search_term){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('voterinfo');
   $this->db->like('firstName', $search_term['firstName']);
   $this->db->like('lastName', $search_term['lastName']);
   $this->db->like('street', $search_term['street']);
   $this->db->like('dob', $search_term['dob']);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();

}
```

Controller:

```
public function search(){
    $this->load->model('reg_model');

    $search_term = array(
    'firstName' => $this->input->post('firstName'),
    'lastName' => $this->input->post('lastName'),
    'street' => $this->input->post('street'),
    'dob' => $this->input->post('dob')
        );


    $data['query'] = $this->reg_model->search_voters($search_term);


    $this->load->view("reg_header");
    $this->load->view("reg_nav");
    $this->load->view("reg_search", $data); 
}
```

View:

```
echo form_open("reg/search");

echo form_label("First Name: ", "firstName");

$data = array(
    "name" => "firstName",
    "id" => "firstName",
    "value" => set_value("firstName")
);    
echo form_input($data);

//last name
echo form_label("Last Name: ", "lastName");

$data = array(
    "name" => "lastName",
    "id" => "lastName",
    "value" => set_value("lastName")
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Street: ", "street");

$data = array(
    "name" => "street",
    "id" => "street",
    "value" => set_value("street")
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_label("Date of Birth: ", "dob");

$data = array(
    "name" => "dob",
    "id" => "dob",
    "value" => set_value("dob")
);    
echo form_input($data);

echo form_submit("searchSubmit", "Search");

echo form_close();




$this->table->set_heading(array('', 'Voter Number', 'First Name', 'Last Name',
                                'mid Initial', 'Home Number', 'Street',
                                'Apt', 'Zip', 'DOB',
                                'Local District', 'State District'));

foreach ($query as $row){

    $this->table->add_row($row);       
}

echo $this->table->generate();
```

**Update**
I've been working on this and came up with something but I am still having issues
Updated View:

```
foreach ($query as $row){
    $this->table->add_row(anchor('reg/view_form/' ,  $row, 'title="VoterNum"'), $row);

}
echo $this->table->generate();
```

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Comment: Perhaps you have to do the update query?

Comment: I want to be able to select from the table I created that gets information  from a database and edit the information with a form. I wanted to know how to accomplish this.

Comment: I suggest looking at the codeigniter documentation for the update query.

Comment: I saw that, but I want to be able to interact with the table that I created for the webpage and choose which row I want to edit from there.

Comment: Obviously you don't understand how MVC works.

Comment: I do understand how they work. What I want to be able to do in my website is go to the search page, which has a table with the results of the search, and click on a row to take me to another form and edit the information of the row from there.

Comment: I gave you the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You shuold probably see jquery and ajax. If certain row from search results is clicked, get a new table with ajax and update the table with new data. ajax will pass your new edited information to controller and in controller, use `$htis->input->is_ajax_request()` test to get the data from ajax, and update the result to database from your model.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have the following.

So using the controller function like so you would.

```
class Whatever extends CI_Controller {
    function whatever() {
        // use whatever code to update data
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only showing me how to create a controller and an function. I know how to do that, I want to create a link from a generated cell in a table. this table is auto generated with data from my database.

Comment: So far I came up with the code below but I am am still having issues `foreach ($query as $row){
        $this->table->add_row(anchor('reg/view_form/' ,  $row, 'title="VoterNum"'), $row);
        
    }
    echo $this->table->generate();`